# Use php mail() function with custom exim installation

Tags: php, exim

I have an exim installation in a non-standard path.

How can I configure php so that mail() will use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the value of the "sendmail_path" variable in php.ini:

```
sendmail_path="/my_custom_path/exim -t -i"
```

exim is compatible to sendmail when it comes to command line arguments

Answer (score 2):

After guarantee that **exim4** is really running without any problem.

```
sudo service exim4 status
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 status
```

**Note**.: Pay attention to result at the command line. It'll warn you, if it has any problem.

```
 * Stopping MTA for restart
 * Restarting MTA
ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has non-zero size, mail system possibly broken
```

You may edit the file

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

and add the line

```
sendmail_path = "/my_custom_path/exim -t"
```

without the option **-i** [which will cause problems.](http://jann.is/daily/archives/741-Cannot-send-mail-with-PHP-and-exim.html)

So, type that to test,

```
echo "Testing." | mail -s Test example@gmail.com
```

instead of test with PHP function. There are so many things (firewall, network: subnets and security groups, PHP settings) that can cause problems to your routine that's better guarantee exim4 works.